# Dynamic action using date picker in APEX 5.0

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to use dynamic action using date picker in APEX 5.0 such that upon selection of `start_date` and `end_date` the interactive report should display the data for the date range selected.

I first created an interactive report in APEX and then created a page items with date pickers.  In my database table, I have a column name `time_stamp` which is of datatype `varchar2` with date format as `YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS`.

My query for interactive report looks like below:

```
Select * from table1 where time_stamp between to_char(to_date(:p1_item,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YY') and to_char(to_date(:p2_item,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YY')
```

( where `p1_item` and `p2_item` are the page items for date pickers), the "Format Mask" attribute for the date pickers I have set to `DD-MM-YY`.  Now I need to define a dynamic action to execute my interactive report SQL query based on the `start_date` and `end_date` selected.  I need to further know the steps to create such a dynamic action and looking for the detailed steps for what attributes needs to set to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, just to be clear, are you trying to make an interactive report that displays data based on the query above?

Comment: Yes I am trying to display an interactive report based on date range.

Answer (score 4):

to get started, change your interactive report query to this:

```
          Select * from table1 
          where  
          (:p1_item is null and :p2_item is null) or time_stamp
          between to_date(:p1_item,'DD-MM-YY') and 
          to_date(:p2_item,'DD-MM-YY')
```

then create a dynamic action under your p2_item. Set its `event` to "change" then set it's `true` action to "submit page"

Comment: I have done exactly what you have mentioned but its not displaying any records while selecting the start_date and end_date from date picker. Do I need to set any other attribute for the interactive report like FORMAT MASK, Post Calculation Computation etc?

Comment: Oh right @Mukul Sharma. I have updated the sql source of your interactive report on my answer. You also have to set the `FORMAT MASK` of your date pickers to `DD-MM-YY`

Comment: Still that doesnot helps. My time_stamp column in table is of varchar2 datatype - is the conversion from varchar to date format not required? and what to set in Post Calculation Computation ?

Comment: you dont have to set anything on your `Post Calculation Computation`. You must alter your time_stamp column to date type for it to work. The reason why its not working is because your current interactive report sql source's `between` operator evaluates it as two strings, not as two dates

Comment: Can  I use date conversion for time_stamp in my sql query instead of changing the data type to date ?

Comment: Yes, you can try it if you haven't yet

Comment: Nice, this is what I was looking for exactly !

Answer (score 2):

A better way to get the data on the page to load would be to create a dynamic action under each date picker.  For each date picker dynamic action set **event** to *change*; set it's true **action** to *Execute Pl/SQL code* and create another true **action** and set it to *refresh*.

For the *Execute Pl/SQL code* put in its code:

```
BEGIN
  null;
END;
```

and set the *Page Items to Submit* to :p1_item (and :P2_item for its corresponding dynamic action).

For the *refresh* action, set *Selection Type* to "region" then set *region* to your interactive report.

Your query should be as @Vance said:

```
  Select * from table1 
  where  
  (:p1_item is null and :p2_item is null) or time_stamp
  between to_date(:p1_item,'DD-MM-YY') and 
  to_date(:p2_item,'DD-MM-YY')
```

Doing it this way will be beneficial down the road as your pages become more complicated and you may not want to submit your entire page from a single date selection.  It also is a little faster as you don't have to wait for the entire page to reload.